# URL preg_replace by domain in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I could not find an optimal solution for this problem. The idea is to change all the urls of a text containing a specific domain with a `preg_replace_callback()` to base 64 codification. The urls are of this type: `http://www.domain.com/?fsdf76sf8sf6fds` and separately the other way: `http://www.otherdomain.com/file/CA60D10F8ACF7CAA`

any ideas for the regex?

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: @Ravinder Singh fixed question, is a  preg_replace_callback() to convert URLs with base 64 function

Comment: Is your example output of "CA60D10F8ACF7CAA" to be taken literally? `base64_encode('fsdf76sf8sf6fds')` returns "ZnNkZjc2c2Y4c2Y2ZmRz"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is something along the lines of

```
$s = preg_replace_callback('#(([a-z]+://)|([a-z]+://)?[a-z0-9.-]+\.|\b)domain.com[^\s]+#i', function($match) {
    return base64_encode($match[0]);
}, $string);
```

That regular expression may be a bit confusing, so let's break it down:

```
(  -- domain.com must be preceeded by either
  ([a-z]+://)   -- a protocol such as http://
  |
  ([a-z]+://)?[a-z0-9.-]+\.  -- possibly a protocol and definitely a subdomain
  |
  \b  -- word-break (prevents otherdomain.com from matching!)
)
domain.com  -- the actual domain you're looking for
[^\s]+  -- everything up to the next space (to include path, query string, fragment)
```

A very simple system to test stuff like this:

```
<?php

$strings = array(
    // positives
    'a http://www.domain.com/?fsdf76sf8sf6fds z' => 'a xxx z',
    'a www.domain.com/?fsdf76sf8sf6fds z' => 'a xxx z',
    'a http://domain.com/?fsdf76sf8sf6fds z' => 'a xxx z',
    'a domain.com/?fsdf76sf8sf6fds z' => 'a xxx z',
    // negatives
    'a http://www.otherdomain.com/file/CA60D10F8ACF7CAA z' => null,
    'a www.otherdomain.com/file/CA60D10F8ACF7CAA z' => null,
    'a http://otherdomain.com/file/CA60D10F8ACF7CAA z' => null,
    'a otherdomain.com/file/CA60D10F8ACF7CAA z' => null,
);

foreach ($strings as $string => $result) {
    $s = preg_replace_callback('#(([a-z]+://)|([a-z]+://)?[a-z0-9.-]+\.|\b)domain.com[^\s]+#i', function($match) {
        return 'xxx';
    }, $string);

    if (!$result) {
        $result = $string;
    }

    if ($s != $result) {
        echo "FAILED: '$string' got '$s'\n";
    } else {
        echo "OK: '$string'\n";
    }
}
```

(should you already be unit testing, use that instead, obviously…)

Answer (score 1):

This answer works only with URLs starting with "http://www.domain.com/" or "https://www.domain.com/", but is much leaner:

```
$in = 'before http://www.domain.com/?fsdf76sf8sf6fds after';

$domain = 'www.domain.com';
echo preg_replace_callback('/\b(https?:\/\/'.preg_quote($domain).'\/)\?(\w+)/i', function($m) {
    return 'http://www.otherdomain.com/file/'.base64_encode($m[2]);
}, $in);
// outputs "before http://www.otherdomain.com/file/ZnNkZjc2c2Y4c2Y2ZmRz after"
```

One issue still to be solved is that your sample output of "CA60D10F8ACF7CAA" shows the base64-encoded output differently that what PHP's base64_encode() returns:

```
echo base64_encode('fsdf76sf8sf6fds'); // outputs ZnNkZjc2c2Y4c2Y2ZmRz
```